# How do I stop FastCGI process exceeding the configured request timeout

Tags: python, iis, fastcgi

I have an API that accepts large files (up to 500Mb). Up until recently it was working. Now I keep getting a `Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error`. The warning message states that `C:\inetpub\Scripts\python.exe - The FastCGI process exceeded configured request timeout`. This appears after about 10 minutes.

Previously the timeout was set to about 20 mins for both CGI and IIS, but since I got this error message, I have upped the timeout ridiculously and it still occurs after about 10 mins.

- In IIS Under CGI I have set the time out to 1h30m.
- In the web.config for IIS I have:

```
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime executionTimeout="12250" maxRequestLength="500000" />
        <customErrors mode="Off" />
    </system.web>
```

Comment: Please check , C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config and entry for <fastCgi>, whether its available there or not , if not then set <fastCgi>
    <application fullPath="C:\inetpub\Scripts\python.exe" idleTimeout="900" activityTimeout="180" requestTimeout="10000" instanceMaxRequests="10000" />
</fastCgi>, and restart sever ....I hope that could work.

Comment: Thanks @Afgan this worked for me. It seems a bit silly to have timeouts in 3 locations but I guess that's life _oO_

Comment: CGI is for classic CGI, not the FastCGI processes. `<system.web>` is for ASP.NET. If you read IIS configuration references, there are other timeout settings, but each have detailed documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please check below config file -

> C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config

,and search entry for , whether its available there or not, if not then set

```
<fastCgi> <application fullPath="C:\inetpub\Scripts\python.exe" idleTimeout="900" activityTimeout="180" requestTimeout="10000" instanceMaxRequests="10000" /> </fastCgi>
```

And restart sever ....I hope that could work

For detailed description please check  [FastCGI Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/fastcgi/application/)

Comment: You'd better link to the official reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/fastcgi/application/